# Comparing Google Analytics and Data from our Hosting Provider

Tags: analytics

Our hosting provider uses an app called AWStats for to give us data about visits/visitors etc. However when I compare that to my google analytics data the numbers are far off. For example AWStats says we had about 5000 visitors but GA says about 1500. How can I uncover the source of the disparity?

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Improper implementation for one or both analytics services
- Different definition of what a visitor is for both analytics services. For example, does GA say that you have 1500 unique visitors? or 1500 visits?

Have you tried using a program like [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) to look at the requests getting sent? Are there duplicate requests?